# Why is complex projective space triangulable?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, combinatorial-geometry, simplicial-stuff, gt.geometric-topology

In an exercise in his algebraic topology book, Munkres asserts that $\mathbf{C}P^n$ is triangulable (i.e., there is a simplicial complex $K$ and a homeomorphism $|K| \rightarrow \mathbf{C}P^n$).  Can anyone provide a reference or a proof?

Comment: All smooth manifolds are triangulable.  This is due to Whitehead.  There's a nice write-up in Whitney's "Geometric Integration Theory". 

Comment: For a more direct proof, one might try using the fact that CP^n is homeomorphic to the n-fold symmetric product of S^2.  Symmetric products don't take simplicial complexes to simplicial complexes, but the quotient of a subdivision of the n-fold product is itself a simplicial complex.

Comment: This seems like a rather elementary exercise? Couldn't you do it by induction?

Comment: Deane, what sort of induction are you imagining?  Given a simplicial structure on `$CP^{n-1}$`, one might try to show that there's some triangulation of the next cell such that after attaching this cell we still have a simplicial complex.  The attaching map is the quotient map `$S^{2n-1} \to CP^{n-1}$`, whose fibers are copies of `$S^1$`.  The inverse image of a point under a simplicial map is always discrete, so this attaching map is definitely not a simplicial map, no matter what simplicial structures you use.  So I think John's question is not so trivial.

Comment: @Dan: what do you mean by a simplicial map? Isn't the map shrinking affinely a triangle (2-simplex) to one of its edges a simplicial map? It doesn't seem to have discrete inverse images...

Comment: By simplicial map, I mean a map that's linear on each simplex.  It's immediate that if you glue two simplicial complexes along a simplicial map, the result is still a simplicial complex; if the map isn't simplicial then you may have to subdivide or otherwise adjust your triangulation.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear comment. The "?"'s were meant to indicate that I wasn't sure and that I might be missing the point. It definitely sounds harder than I thought. But it seems a shame to give away the answer to something left as an exercise in Munkres.

Comment: Oh, triangulating CP^n isn't an exercise in Munkres; rather, one of his exercises says something like, "Assume that CP^n can be triangulated (it can be). Then use the Lefschetz fixed point theorem to ..." -- the statement of the Lefschetz fixed point theorem requires that the space be triangulable.  I was looking for justification for his parenthetical remark.

Comment: I'm still a bit surprised that there isn't a way to triangulate $CP^n$ more easily than an arbitrary smooth manifold. Using google, I found the following short paper by Cairns on triangulations of smooth manifolds: http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.bams/1183524257

Comment: I think that with some ingenuity you can triangulate the cofiber of a simplicial map. Then induction and simplicial approximation do it.

Comment: Follow-up:  This is done on p. 183 of Hatcher's book.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will present a triangulation of $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$. More specifically, I will give an explicit regular CW structure on $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$. As spinorbundle says, the first barycentric subdivision of a regular CW complex is a simplicial complex homeomorphic to the original CW complex.

---

Recall that to put a regular CW complex on space $X$ means to decompose $X$ into disjoint pieces $Y_i$ such that:

(1) The closure of each $Y_i$ is a union of $Y$'s.

(2) For each $i$, the pair $(\overline{Y_i}. Y_i)$ is homemorphic to $(\mbox{closed}\ d-\mbox{ball}, \mbox{interior of that}\  d-\mbox{ball})$ for some $d$.

The barycentric subdivision of $X$ corresponding to this regular CW complex is the simplicial complex which has a vertex for each $Y_i$ and has a simplex $(i_0, i_1, \ldots, i_r)$ if and only if $\overline{Y_{i_0}} \subset \overline{Y_{i_1}} \subset \cdots \subset \overline{Y_{i_r}}$.

---

Write $(t_1: t_2: \ldots: t_n)$ for the homogeneous coordinates on $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$. For $I$ a nonempty subset of $\{ 1,2, \ldots, n \}$, let $Z_I$ be the subset of $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ where $|t_i|=|t_{i'}|$ for $i$ and $i' \in I$ and $|t_i| > |t_j|$ for $i \in I$ and $j \not \in I$. Note that $Z_I \cong (S^1)^{|I|-1} \times D^{2(n-|I|)}$, where $D^k$ is the open $k$-disc. Also, $\overline{Z_I} = \bigcup_{J \supseteq I} Z_J \cong (S^1)^{|I|-1} \times \overline{D}^{2(n-|I|)}$ where $\overline{D}^k$ is the closed $k$-disc.

We now cut those torii into discs. For $i$ and $i'$ in $I$, cut $Z_I$ along $t_i=t_{i'}$ and $t_i = - t_{i'}$. So the combinatorial data indexing a face of this subdivision is a cyclic arrangement of the symbols $i$ and $-i$, for $i \in I$, with $i$ and $-i$ antipodal to each other. For example, let $I=\{ 1,2,3,4,5 \}$ and write $t_k=e^{i \theta_k}$ for $k \in I$. Then one of our faces corresponds to the situation that, cyclically, 
$$\theta_1 < \theta_2 = \theta_4 + \pi < \theta_3 = \theta_5 < \theta_1+ \pi < \theta_2 + \pi = \theta_4 < \theta_3 + \pi = \theta_5 + \pi < \theta_1.$$
This cell is clearly homeomorphic to $\{ (\alpha, \beta) : 0 < \alpha < \beta < \pi \}$. Similarly, each of these cells is an open ball, and each of their closures is a closed ball. We have put a CW structure on the torus.

Cross this subdivision of the torus with the open disc $D^{2(n-|I|)}$. The result, if I am not confused, is a regular $CW$ decomposition of $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$.

Comment: After thinking about it for a while, this looks good to me.  I have to think about it some more before I'll be completely convinced, but so far it looks very nice.



Comment: According to the authors of
http://uk.arxiv.org/abs/1012.3235
"no explicit triangulation of $CP^3$ was known so far".

Answer (score 3):

Here is an article on explicit triangulation on $CP^n$, http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.2568.

Answer (score 3):

Although I am more than a decade late to the discussion, here is an alternate approach to an explicit triangulation of $\mathbb{C}P^n$.

(1) A simplicial set $X$ is a natural generalization of a simplicial complex with locally ordered vertices.  $X$ has a realization $|X|$ which is a CW complex, with a cell for each non-degenerate simplex $\sigma \in X$.  However, $X$ may or may not be regular as a CW complex.

(2) If $X$ is a simplicial set, then so is its $n$th symmetric power $X^n/S_n$, and miraculously $|X^n/S_n| \cong |X|^n/S_n$ (since [geometric realization preserves finite limits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+realization)).  In particular we can let $|X| \cong S^2 \cong \mathbb{C}P^1$ by collapsing the boundary of a triangle to a point.   Then $|X^n/S_n| \cong \mathbb{C}P^n$ is a canonical simplicial set model of $\mathbb{C}P^n$.

(3) Finally, there is a canonical way to subdivide a simplicial set to make a simplicial complex; see [arXiv:2001.04339](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04339). It is a modified second barycentric subdivision and is not all that efficient of a triangulation, but it works.

(4) You can make the construction a little more efficient by letting $|X| \cong S^2$ be the boundary of a tetrahedron.  Then I believe that $|X^n/S_n|$ is a regular cellulation of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ with simplices, so that its first barycentric subdivision is already an honest simplicial complex.

Answer (score 2):

I think the comments answer the question, but to give you a reference:

Milnor, Stasheff: [Characteristic Classes](http://books.google.de/books?id=5zQ9AFk1i4EC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_slider_thumb#v=onepage&q&f=false), Chapter 6

They prove that every Grasmann manifold $G_n(\mathbb{R}^m)$ is a CW-Complex. (The cells are constructed with Schubert symbols). The complex case works in the same fashion.
 
As a result you get that $\mathbb{CP}^n$ consists of $n+1$ cells: for every $0 \leq k \leq n$ you get one $2k$-cell. The $2k$-skeleton is a $\mathbb{CP}^k$

**EDIT:** Sorry for the sloppiness!
Not every CW-Complex is triangulable, but the following holds:
**Every regular CW-Complex (<strike>and $\mathbb{CP}^n$ is a regular complex</strike> $\oplus$) $X$ is triangulable**.
 
This is true, since the barycentric subdivision is a simplicial complex that is homeomorphic to $X$. For a full proof, see for example [Cellular structures in topology](http://books.google.de/books?id=J-2F641zx-MC&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=CW-Complex+triangulable&source=bl&ots=857Bjqzpce&sig=RZO51f71tCOvbnqiyIKfSAO_isQ&hl=de&ei=bla-S4-lOYOvOPqK1ZYE&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CA4Q6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=CW-Complex%20triangulable&f=false) (p.130) by Fritsch and Piccinini.

**Edit 2:** $\oplus$: Perhaps the next sloppiness: The CW-structure of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ obtained by Schubert cells isn't regular (the characteristic map is 2-to-1) but I think there exists a regular CW-structure. But this might be harder to prove than I thought?!

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't know much about triangulations.  Why does a CW-complex structure guarantee a simplicial complex structure?


Comment: The characteristic map isn't 2-to-1, it collapses an entire dimension! That is to say, the big cell in $\mathbb{CP}^n$ is $2n$ dimensional, so its boundary should be $S^{2n-1}$, but it is glued to $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$, which has dimension $2n-2$. (You might be thinking of $\mathbb{RP}^n$.)

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of RP^n. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1):

An online search yielded a reference to
Francis Sergeraert's paper, Triangulations of complex projective spaces,
available at http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~sergerar/Papers/ .
But, to quote the author:
"The Kenzo program is used to automatically produce triangulations of the complex projective spaces $P^nC$ as simplicial sets, more precisely of spaces having the right homotopy type. The homeomorphism question between the obtained objects and the projective spaces is open."

Comment: I've browsed through some of Sergeraert's work before, but I hadn't seen this paper. Unfortunately, it seems to deal with simplicial sets, not simplicial complexes, and it's not clear how to get from a simplicial set structure to a simplicial complex structure.  Is it?

(A preprint by Lutz (http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0506372) says that explicit triangulations, as simplicial complexes, of CP^n are not known for n>2.)


Comment: Thanks, John. As Sergeraert says, he hasn't proved
his triangulations actually are homeomorphic to $CP^n$!
It's still a surprise that explicit triangulations
are apparently not known, but on first sight, Tyler's
idea looks sound to me. It shows the problem is
harder than it looks.

Comment: If anyone is still interested, a paper on triangulations of $CP^2$
by Bagchi and Datta appeared on the ArXiV today:
http://uk.arxiv.org/abs/1004.3157 .